# loading a large xml file and comparing data

Tags: c#, xml

i have a large xml file and i want to search through the Desc nodes in it to see if any match the text a user inputs then if it does get the data from the code node directly underneath the Desc node this is an example of the xml im using except mine has around 1000 Script nodes in it

```
<Scripts>
 <script>
   <Name>mst</Name>
  <Desc>Destroy 1 spell/trap on the field</Desc>
  <code>function c????????.initial_effect(c)
    --Activate
    local e1=Effect.CreateEffect(c)
    e1:SetCategory(CATEGORY_DESTROY)
    e1:SetType(EFFECT_TYPE_ACTIVATE)
    e1:SetCode(EVENT_FREE_CHAIN)
    e1:SetHintTiming(0,TIMING_END_PHASE+TIMING_EQUIP)
    e1:SetProperty(EFFECT_FLAG_CARD_TARGET)
    e1:SetTarget(c????????.target)
    e1:SetOperation(c????????.activate)
    c:RegisterEffect(e1)
end
function c????????.filter(c)
    return c:IsDestructable() and c:IsType(TYPE_SPELL+TYPE_TRAP)
end
function c????????.target(e,tp,eg,ep,ev,re,r,rp,chk,chkc)
    if chkc then return chkc:IsOnField() and c????????.filter(chkc) end
    if chk==0 then return Duel.IsExistingTarget(c????????.filter,tp,LOCATION_ONFIELD,LOCATION_ONFIELD,1,e:GetHandler()) end
    Duel.Hint(HINT_SELECTMSG,tp,HINTMSG_DESTROY)
    local g=Duel.SelectTarget(tp,c????????.filter,tp,LOCATION_ONFIELD,LOCATION_ONFIELD,1,1,e:GetHandler())
    Duel.SetOperationInfo(0,CATEGORY_DESTROY,g,1,0,0)
end
function c????????.activate(e,tp,eg,ep,ev,re,r,rp)
    local tc=Duel.GetFirstTarget()
    if tc:IsRelateToEffect(e) then
        Duel.Destroy(tc,REASON_EFFECT)
    end
end</code>
 </script>
</Scripts>
```

this is the code i found online but it doesnt seem to work

```
    public static string Xmlload(String node)
    {
        XmlTextReader script = new XmlTextReader("Scripts.xml");
        while (script.Read())
        {
            if (script.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                script.LocalName == node &&
                script.IsStartElement() == true)
            {
                ProcessRewardNode(script,node);
                script.Skip();
                return myID;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        myID = "test";
        return myID;
    }
    private static void ProcessRewardNode(XmlTextReader RewardReader, string node)
    {
        XmlDocument RewardXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        RewardXmlDoc.LoadXml(RewardReader.ReadOuterXml());
        // we can use xpath as below
        myID = RewardXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(node).InnerText;
    }

    public static string myID { get; set; }
```

hope someone can help thanks

Comment: How large is the file in MB and how frequent do you need to search on it?

Comment: everytime a user presses a button and the file is 1.24 GB or 1240.97 MB plus users will be able to add codes in so it will get bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.  I added `using` to properly dispose of the `XmlTextReader` after use.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Xmlload("Destroy 1 spell/trap on the field"));
}

public static string Xmlload(String textUserInputs)
{
   using (var script = new XmlTextReader("Scripts.xml"))
   {
        while (script.Read())
        {
            if (script.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                script.LocalName == "Desc" &&
                script.IsStartElement() == true)
            {
                    var desc = script.ReadElementContentAsString();

                    if (desc == textUserInputs)
                    {
                        script.ReadToNextSibling("code");

                        return script.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
            }
        }
   }

   return null;
}
```

### References

[XmlTextReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)